# Should I finish my undergrad in 3 years (this year) or 4 years? Which option is better for graduate school application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application

Chemistry major, I can graduate this year with a high GPA (3.95+, with 2-3 graduate-level class) decent research (2 year+, started in freshmen year) and likely 2 publications (one first author, one second author, both on journals with IF around 6).

My biggest concern is the recommendation letter. Having one less year is really hard for getting recommendation letters. I stayed in my school for my freshmen summer research. Also this year because of covid. So I may end up with only one strong recommendation letter from my research advisor.

Does the fact that I can graduate in 3 years outshine the recommendation letters problem?

Or It's best for me to just take another year for getting more publication and get a summer research position so I'll get a recommendation letter from professors in other university?

Comment: Hard to understand that you can't get good letters with that GPA, etc.

Comment: Nobody cares how long it took you to graduate from your BS.c, so whatever you decide to do, make sure that it will make you will have a *bigger bag* by the time you graduate.

Comment: @Buffy I worry about letters from professors who only taught me in the class are not as good as professors that I did research with. Also the letters are limited in only one university (I had no interns in other universities).

Comment: If this is for US study, don't put extreme importance on anyone item. Build a complete picture of your likely future success. And, it might be a mistake to "waste" a year just for something ephemeral. There might be other reasons to do another year, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no benefit to graduating in less time except getting a year ahead. No one will be impressed by a 3 year graduation.

It's more important that you show proficiency in courses related to your intended area of study, and obtain research experience.

If someone's option was to graduate a year early or do a research project, I think the answer is obvious: stay and research. You have some research experience already, so your decision seems mostly between applying right away for grad school or gathering more experience for awhile and then graduating. The choice is entirely yours, there is no "best" answer.

Comment: The reason that I want to graduate in 3 year is I want to start my graduate program as soon as possible. I spent a ton of time in the lab and I definitively love workin in lab. I think I'll let the admission committee to decide wether I'm proficient enough. Since I can always switch back to 4 years maybe I'll decide after the application result next year.

Comment: @Nitrogen Seems reasonable - like I said, that's your trade-off to consider.

Comment: Another thing to consider is how covid is effecting applications, whether it will be harder to start with covid going on or after (since there may also be a flood of students/postdocs at this time as well, or a change in the amount of funding avaliable). I do know covid's placed hiring freezes in some US universities. But someone more knowledgeable than me should be answering this aspect.

Comment: Outside the US 3 year bachelors are normal (so I was initially confused by why finishing in 3 years kept being brought up). If you do another year (having completed the chemistry component) you could look taking courses in other fields. More advanced knowledge of maths/physics/biology could place you in a more unique position and might give some insight in future research/position your for a particular research field. Worst case they become weird courses you did in undergrad that you surprise your lab with your breadth of knowledge. Edit: specifically programs in EU, UK, Australia, Canada